# Merging 2 sorted linked lists. Required member function bool Merge(List342 &list1):

Tags: c++, merge, linked-list, mergesort

C++ Linked List
The prompt for this function is as follows:

bool Merge(List342 &list1):

Takes a sorted list and merges into the calling sorted list
(no new memory should be allocated). At termination of function, the list passed in (list1)
should be empty (unless it is the calling list). No duplicates are allowed

(My insert function checks for duplicates and removes them)

I am having a hard time implementing this function. If I was able to have a function with 2 arguments that take in 2 linked lists I would be able to solve. However I do not and am confused on how to start or visualize this function.

Comment: We can't help with your code that we can't see. Please create a [mcve]

Comment: ***My insert function checks for duplicates and removes them*** You probably should just skip inserting the duplicate in the first place.

Comment: ***I am having a hard time implementing this function. If I was able to have a function with 2 arguments that take in 2 linked lists I would be able to solve.*** You could create a new list in merge. Then at the end swap the head node pointers and free the other list.

Answer (score 0):

Note the title states "member function". So the implication is that you need to create a linked list class, then merge a second list into the current list, for example, assuming the class name is List342

```
    List342 list1, list2;
    // create sorted lists in list1 and list2.
    list1.Merge(list2);   // merge list2 into list1
```

"no duplicates allowed" could mean that it's assumed that no duplicates are present in either list (which really isn't an issue), or possible that duplicates are to be removed, or just noting that the two list can't share nodes (if "no duplicates" refers to nodes as opposed to node values).